# Any undirected graph on 9 vertices with minimum degree at least 5 contains a subgraph $K_4$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, ramsey-theory, extremal-graph-theory

> Let $G$ be simple undirected graph with degree of every vertices is at least 5. Prove or disprove that $G$ contains subgraph $K_4$.

I came up with this question when I were trying to find Ramsey number $R(4,3)$. I think my conjecture is correct but I am unable to prove it. If anyone have any idea please share with me. Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The complete tripartite graph $K_{3,3,3}$ is a $6$-regular graph on $9$ vertices and has chromatic number $3$ so it contains no $K_4.$

By [Turán's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem), a simple graph with $9$ vertices and more than $27$ edges must contain $K_4$ as a subgraph, and $K_{3,3,3}$ (also known as the Turán graph $T(9,3)$) is the unique $K_4$-free simple graph with $9$ vertices and $27$ edges.

Answer (score 2):

If $\chi(G)=3$, the graph cannot contain any $K_4$ as a subgraph:

[image]

The above graph is just a $K_9$ with only $9$ edges removed, in particular a $K_{3,3,3}$, with chromatic number $3$, as clear from the picture (no couple of vertices with the same colour is joined by an edge, but the graph has plenty of embedded triangles).

On the other hand, [it is not difficult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem) to show that any graph on $9$ vertices with more than $27$ edges has a subgraph isomorphic to $K_4$. Quite disappointing and not even surprising, since a graph fulfilling such constraints is full of triangles and almost complete:

[image]

Comment: Yes, $27$ is the maximum possible number of edges in a $K_4$-free graph on $9$ vertices; this is an instance of [Turán's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, since the sum of degrees across the 9 vertices must be even, there must be a vertex with degree at least $6$, meaning that only 2 vertices are isolated from this vertex. Choose the vertex of highest degree (degree-$6$ or higher) and label it as $A$ and the vertices connected it, the "linked set", as  $\{B,C,D,E,F,G\}$. Each of these will have an additional minimum $4$ links to make in addition to the link to $A$, so at least $2$ of these in each case are within the linked set. So this gives 6 vertices and minimum 6 edges in the linked set, which can be connect as a ring to avoid triangles. Then the other two verrtices, $\{H,I\}$ can be connected to each point on the ring (but not to each other) to avoid any $K_4$.

A diagram of this:

[image]