# For any simple graph $G$ with 9 vertices, either it must have a subgraph isomorphic to $K_4$ or $G^{C}$ must have a subgraph isomorphic to $K_3$

Tags: graph-theory

How to prove the following

> For any simple graph $G$ with 9 vertices, either it must have a
> subgraph isomorphic to $K_4$ or $G^{C}$ must have a subgraph
> isomorphic to $K_3$, where $K_n$ denotes the complete graph with $n$
> vertices.

I am trying to prove this without using Turan's theorem. So far my thinking is that $G \cup G^{C} = K_9$ which has 36 edges. But I am not sure this is the correct way to proceed.

Comment: Why do you want to prove it "without using Turán's theorem"? What makes you think Turán's theorem would be useful here? Do you have an idea for a proof using Turán's theorem? (I don't.)

Comment: Do you know any theorem which is sort of like this one but simpler? Have you heard one like this: "For any graph $G$ on $6$ vertices, either $G$ or $G^C$ must have a subgraph isomorphic to $K_3$."

Comment: @user14111 I bring up Turan's theorem because of this answer to a similar question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1838619/504899

Comment: Hint: Consider two cases. (1) There is a vertex of degree at least $6$. (2) There is a vertex of degree at most $4$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Think of the Ramsey number $R(3,4)$.